# How does an SMTP server resolve ambiguity?

Tags: email, smtp

Suppose I own an email 'demo@gmail.com'. Now, I create a new Microsoft account using my existing email. Thus I get another email 'demo@gmail.com', but this one is served by Microsoft.

So the situation is: one email and two providers.

If I send a hello email to 'demo@gmail.com' using my personal SMTP server, to which of the above will it send: will it send to the one hosted by Microsoft or the one hosted by Google?

How does it solve such an ambiguity? What are the factors that influence this?

This is a very common problem because many providers are giving us an option to create a new account using our existing email.

**My observations**:

1. I saw the emails inside the inboxes of both the services. I found that they had completely different emails.
2. There was no email which was common to both the inboxes. So there must be some mechanism to deal with it.
3. Let us look at the problem the other way round: If I had an email 'demo@outlook.com' initially and I created a new Google Account with this email address, then:
   An email sent to this email address from another gmail account goes to the Google's server. An email sent to this email address from an Outlook also goes to the Google's servers.

Comment: You don't get another demo@gmail.com email address, and no gmail.com email is served by microsoft. One email address is never shared by two providers. There is no ambiguity. The email address domain is resolved, and that determines the SMTP server that handles the email. That said, your question doesn't make much sense to me. Either way, it's not programming related, so it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways of looking up an email. The 'normal' way:

You send an email to an server, in this example `gmail.com`.

Your mail delivery agent looks for mx record of `gmail.com`and send it to the ip-address of `gmail.com`.

If an email is delivered locally by the domain `outlook.com` it perhaps doesn't lookup the mx record, but lookups in a local database if the email-address exist there, and sends it to the ip-address of the outlook.com.

I think in the inbox of outlook.com are only microsoft emails.

More details can be found at https://www.socketlabs.com/blog/smtp-email-delivery/